# Mongodb find all documents that match multiple regex's

Tags: javascript, regex, mongodb, find

I'm trying to query a database to find all documents that match multiple of regex terms in one field, AND matching another list of regex terms in another field.

eg.

```
    .find({
      fieldA: { $regex: /stringA/i } OR 
      fieldA: { $regex: /stringB/i } AND
      fieldB: { $regex: /stringC/i } OR
      fieldB: { $regex: /stringD/i },
    })
```

I currently have arrived at the below which finds results matching all regex terms.

```
    .find({
      fieldA: { $regex: /termA/i },
      fieldA: { $regex: /termB/i },
      fieldB: { $regex: /termC/i },
      fieldB: { $regex: /termD/i },
    })
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```js
.find({
  fieldA: { $regex: /termA|termB/i },
  fieldB: { $regex: /termC|termD/i },
})
```

> See ["or" in regular expressions: `|`](https://www.ocpsoft.org/tutorials/regular-expressions/or-in-regex/)